# how to connect to wamp server from another computer/different pc

Tags: vb.net, connection, client-server, wamp, wampserver

I have created an application in VB. I have successfully connected the application to wamp localhost (same computer). But I can't connect it from another computer that is in the same network. Please help me to connect...

here is my code:

```
    Dim server1 As String
    Dim client1 As String

    Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
    server1 = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=db_checkvoucher;User=root;Password=;Option=3;"

    client1 = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=192.168.1.2;" _
        & "User=root;Password=;" _
        & "database=db_checkvoucher;"

    If Form1.TextBox1.Text = "1" Then
        con.ConnectionString = client1
    Else
        con.ConnectionString = server1
    End If

    cmd.Connection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(con.ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
```

I am getting this error: 
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.2' (10060) ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.2' (10060)
I have already run wamp server on the server computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably an issue with your firewall on the server.

See here for notes on how to allow mysql connections. http://portforward.com/english/routers/firewalling/Microsoft/WindowsXPFirewallFirewall/MySQL_Server.htm